# Cgo pointer passing rule for pointer string slice (*[]string)?

Tags: pointers, go, cgo

Can I pass `*[]string` to C from Go and then `append` to the string slice, or is it violating the [pointer passing spec](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers)?

> Go code may pass a Go pointer to C, provided the Go memory to which it points does not contain any Go pointers.

Example code:

```
package main

/*
extern void go_callback(void*, char*);

static inline void callback(void* stringSliceGoPointer) {
    go_callback(stringSliceGoPointer, "foobar");
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    a := make([]string, 0)
    C.callback(unsafe.Pointer(&a)) 
    fmt.Println(a[0]) // outputs foobar
}

//export go_callback
func go_callback(stringSliceGoPointer unsafe.Pointer, msg *C.char) {
    slice := (*[]string)(stringSliceGoPointer)
    *slice = append(*slice, C.GoString(msg))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a `*[]string` to C is not allowed because the memory pointed to contains strings and strings contain pointers. As [the cgo docs](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers) say (emphasis mine)

> Note that **values of some Go types**, other than the type's zero value,
>   **always include Go pointers. This is true of string**, slice, interface, channel, map, and function types.

One way to overcome this is to refer to the `[]string` more indirectly so only Go code actually knows its address. For example:

```
package main

/*
extern void go_callback(int, char*);

static inline void callback(int stringSliceRef) {
    go_callback(stringSliceRef, "foobar");
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

// If you need to use these values concurrently,
// you'll need more code to protect this.
var stringSlices = make([][]string, 10)

func main() {
    C.callback(0) 
    fmt.Println(stringSlices[0][0]) // outputs foobar
}

//export go_callback
func go_callback(ref C.int, msg *C.char) {
    i := int(ref)
    stringSlices[i] = append(stringSlices[i], C.GoString(msg))
}
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as it provides a possible solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

No, It's not possible.

Refer [this](https://research.swtch.com/godata) for further explanation of go data types.

Basically a string type in Go looks something like this.

```
str := "hello"
```

This is stored as,

```
 str:                0xad234e3b:
 ┌──────────┬─┐      ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
 |0xad234e3b|5|  ┌──>|104|101|108|108|111| -->[5]byte
 └────┬─────┴─┘  |   └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
      └──────────┘
```

Consider a slice:

```
arr := string{"hi!","hello"}
```

Further Slice data type contains pointer, length, capacity.

```
arr:                   0xd2b564c7:        0xad234e40:
┌──────────┬─┬─┐       ┌──────────┬─┐     ┌───┬───┬──┐
|0xd2b564c7|2|2|  ┌──> |0xad234e40|3|────>|104|105|33| -->[3]byte
└────┬─────┴─┴─┘  |    ├──────────┼─┤     └───┴───┴──┘
     └────────────┘    |0xad234e4b|5|──┐  0xad234e4b:
                       └──────────┴─┘  |  ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
                                       └─>|104|101|108|108|111| -->[5]byte
                                          └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Where the hex value represents address.

Where the actual data is stored is of an array of `[x]byte`.

`x` represents the size of data(array).

It's clear `[]string` itself contains many(`x`) pointers, whereas `*[]string` is one more additional pointer.

Comment: Meaning `[]string` is really just `[][]byte` which is a byte slice which then translates to an array? So it's a pointer to a pointer violating the spec?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written the whole answer, It's posted by mistake, I'm still writing the answer.